# Tabular: Good shaping but uncorrect number of columns

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create a tabular with a given shaping. But I'm not able to change the number of column and keep the shaping as the same time.

There is an image of the "expected" tabular (made by Excel) :

[image]

There is an image the result :

[image]

I just need to have 15 columns and not 4.

There is the code for the tabular:

```
\documentclass[3p,11pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{epstopdf,cmap,amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,stmaryrd,mathtext,enumerate,float,natbib,indentfirst,hyperref,graphicx,multirow,color,setspace}
% lmodern used for good quality english font rendering.
\usepackage{lmodern}

\graphicspath{{figures/en/}}

\journal{Journal Title}

\begin{document}

\section{Results}
\label{sec:Results}

\begin{table*}[!h]
\caption{Eigenvalue and variance of the components (Comp.)}
\label{tab:}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.05 pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lrrr}
\hline
Components & \textit{C 1} & \textit{C 2} & \textit{C 3} & \textit{C 4} & \textit{C 5} & \textit{C 5} & \textit{C 6} & \textit{C 7} & \textit{C 8} & \textit{C 9} & \textit{C 10} & \textit{C 11} & \textit{C 12} & \textit{C 13} & \textit{C 14} \\
\hline

\multicolumn{15}{l}{\textit{Eigenvalue}} \\
PCA 1 & 4.76\textsuperscript{*}  & 1.82\textsuperscript{*} & 1.56\textsuperscript{*} & 1.03\textsuperscript{*} & 0.92 & 0.88 & 0.88 & 0.74 & 0.49 & 0.29 & 0.25 & 0.22 & 0.17 & 0.06 \\
PCA 2 & 3.34\textsuperscript{*}  & 1.72\textsuperscript{*} & 1.54\textsuperscript{*} & 1.02\textsuperscript{*} & 0.91 & 0.87 & 0.8 & 0.69 & 0.45 & 0.27 & 0.25 & 0.13 & & \\

\multicolumn{15}{l}{\textit{Percentage of variance}} \\
PCA 1 & 34  & 13 & 11.2 & 7.3 & 6.6 & 6.3 & 5.73 & 5.3 & 3.5 & 2.1 & 1.8 & 1.6 & 1.2 & 0.06 \\
PCA 2 & 27.9  & 14.4 & 12.8 & 8.5 & 7.6 & 7.3 & 6.7 & 5.8 & 3.7 & 2.3 & 2 & 1.1 & &  \\

\hline
\end{tabular*}
\begin{spacing}{0.5}
{\scriptsize Note: '*' in the tabular indicate a value which can be considerate as significant.}
\end{spacing}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your table code fragment to complete document with your table, which begin with  `\documentclass` followed by necessary preamble, than `begin{table} <your table code> \end{table}\end{document}`. btw, you declare only four columns in your table, but like to have 15 ...

Comment: @Zarko I completed the code in the question. Nevertheless, I don't see were I declare only four columns... (I'm new in LaTeX)

Comment: @C.Guffens: In `\begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lrrr}` you use `lrrr` which denotes 4 columns: `l`eft, `r`ight, `r`ight and `r`ight-aligned. You might be interested in `l *{14}{r}` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with use correct number of column, `S` column type for all columns except the first one, `threeparttablex` for table notes and the `booktabs` for table rules, remove erroneous double column header `\textit{C 5}`, the *mwe* with your table is:

```
\documentclass[3p,11pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex} % <--- for \note, \source
% lmodern used for good quality english font rendering.
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[tb]
\caption{Eigenvalue and variance of the components (Comp.)}
\label{tab:}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0 pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{14}{S[table-format=2.2]}} %<--- main changes
    \toprule
Components  & \textit{C 1} & \textit{C 2} & \textit{C 3} & \textit{C 4} & \textit{C 5}
            & \textit{C 6} & \textit{C 7} & \textit{C 8} & \textit{C 9} &\textit{C 10} &\textit{C 11} &\textit{C 12} &\textit{C 13} &\textit{C 14} \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{15}{l}{\textit{Eigenvalue}} \\
PCA 1       & 4.76\tnote{*}& 1.82\tnote{*}& 1.56\tnote{*}& 1.03\tnote{*}& 0.92
            & 0.88         & 0.88         & 0.74         & 0.49         & 0.29
            & 0.25         & 0.22         & 0.17         & 0.06 \\
PCA 2       & 3.34\tnote{*}& 1.72\tnote{*}& 1.54\tnote{*}& 1.02\tnote{*}& 0.91
            & 0.87         & 0.8          & 0.69         & 0.45         & 0.27
            & 0.25         & 0.13         &              &      \\

\multicolumn{15}{l}{\textit{Percentage of variance}}            \\
PCA 1       & 34           & 13           & 11.2         & 7.3          & 6.6
            & 6.3          & 5.73         & 5.3          & 3.5          & 2.1
            & 1.8          & 1.6          & 1.2          & 0.06 \\
PCA 2       & 27.9         & 14.4         & 12.8         & 8.5          & 7.6
            & 7.3          & 6.7          & 5.8          & 3.7          & 2.3
            & 2            & 1.1          &              &      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]
\note The "*" indicate a value which can be considerate as significant.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

( in preamble i remove all not used packages)

[image]